# How to compute sum of a field value across documents in mongodb using python (pymongo)

Tags: python, mongodb, aggregate, pymongo

I have a few documents of the following structure stored in MongoDB:

```
DOCUMENT 1
{
   "_id":{
      "$oid":"634c4eb3421aa4567782ffc7af"
   },
   "name":"John Doe",
   "wins":{
      "texas":{
         "football":{
            "count":1,
         },
         "basketball":{
            "open_count":1,
         }
      }
   }
}

DOCUMENT 2
{
   "_id":{
      "$oid":"634c4eb3421aa4567782ffc7af"
   },
   "name":"Johnny Doey",
   "wins":{
      "texas":{
         "football":{
            "count":3,
         },
         "basketball":{
            "open_count":4,
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Here, I am trying to get the wins for a student by a game type.
Example: the result should be able to tell me the total wins in football (both students included). With the above documents, the total (1+3 = 4, i.e. 1 win for John Doe + 1 win for Johnny Doey).

I am not able to arrive at the right pymongo aggregate query for this case. Requesting comments on how can this be achieved.

I have tried `group by` but that works on the values and not on the keys of the documents (football being the key in this case to compute wins for all students in football).

Answer (score 0):

okay, so I figured out the answer. What I was trying with $group was in the right direction however there were some issues with how I had written the query.

This works to compute the aggregate sum of wins for football.

```
collection.aggregate([{ 
  '$group': { 
      '_id':None, 
      'total': { '$sum': '$wins.texas.football.count' }
  }
}])
```